# NSStatusBarButton with a NSHostingView autosize

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have a `NSStatusBarButton` that contains a `NSHostingView` containing a Swift UI View.
I'd like that my Button and his subview to be the size of the Swift UI view content size.

The code looks like that:

```swift
// CustomSwiftUIView

import SwiftUI

struct CustomSwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world, I have a dynamic width :)")    
    }
}
```

```swift
// AppDelegate
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            let mySwiftUIView = CustomSwiftUIView()
            let innerView = NSHostingView(rootView: mySwiftUIView);
            button.addSubview(innerView)
         }
     }
}
```

If I don't explicitly set a width and an height to the Button AND to the `innerView`, the button size is `0,0` and nothing is displayed.

Any idea how I can achieve the desired behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey Vincent, Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hey AW101. Unfortunately not really. The solution was to add a Geometry Reader to the underlining view to get the width, and update the parent view when the width is updated. Didn't find a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks. That's ultimately what I've had to do too.